# Couchbase PHP SDK throws error message: Can’t find class CouchbaseN1qlQuery N1QL

Tags: php, couchbase, sql++

I'm using Couchbase PHP client version 2.0.1 which I've installed via pecl. Unfortunatley it seems to miss the class CouchbaseN1qlQuery. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you search the documentation?  What did you find?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Couchbase C language SDK? Looks like this is a pre-requisite for the Couchbase PHP SDK: http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/php-2.0/download-links.html